# Tensorflow: why softmax outputs [1, 0, 0..., 0]

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I have a neural net model, it's last layer is fully connected layer with 9 output neurons. 
To train my network correctly, I'm using softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits. 
It trains ok, but when I want to evaluate my model, I want probabilities also. 
So I take an evaluation sample and feed it to the network. 
After that I apply softmax to the output and get 
    `[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]]`

Here unnormalized probabilites also:

```
[[ -2710.10620117  -2914.37866211  -5045.04443359  -4361.91601562
-459.57000732   8843.65820312  -1871.62756348   5447.12451172
-10947.22949219]]
```

I'm also getting probility of 1 and rest are zeros.
Could anyone please help to handle this issue?

EDIT:
Input images are of shape 64 * 160. 
All activation functions are relu. 
Max poolings are 2x2. 
In conv_plus_max_pool_layer(x_image, 5, 1, 96) 5 is kernel size. 
Here is network layout:

```
hidden_block_1 = conv_plus_max_pool_layer(x_image, 5, 1, 96)
hidden_block_2 = conv_plus_max_pool_layer(hidden_block_1, 5, 96, 256)
hidden_block_3 = conv_plus_max_pool_layer(hidden_block_2, 3, 256, 384)
hidden_block_4 = conv_plus_max_pool_layer(hidden_block_3, 3, 384, 512)

fc1 = dropout_plus_fc(4 * 10 * 512, 512, hidden_block_4, keep_prob_drop1)
output = dropout_plus_fc(512, model_net10_train.class_num, fc1, keep_prob_drop2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your network is pretty sure about the output ;)

In this case, I don't think we can do a lot for you without your network layout... Some gut feelings from my side: the layer leading up to your output layer has too many nodes (thus giving you these huuuge numbers), and I suspect that you don't use nonlinearities such as RELU, or tanh. Another thing you might want to check are the initial values for the weights (might be too big), and the learning rate you are using (might be too high).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Added network layout and more details. Could you please make more suggestions please?

Comment: Well, my best suggestion would be to start following a course like the Udacity course on deep learning, or the Kadenze course for creative applications of deep learning. This way you learn everything while having fun!

Comment: I will do that but right now could you please point me the right direction?

Comment: I think many people are willing to help you if you can formulate your questions as a StackOverflow question. For now I think you can explore my suggestions and follow a course.

Comment: I would like to say Thanks to you. The course is awesome. It is much better than ready to use answer.